# Hibernate 6 regression with generics

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, regression

I tried to migrate my application from Hibernate `5.4.30.Final` to `6.1.6.Final`, database H2 2.1.214. I observed a different behaviour regarding generics when using a `CriteriaQuery`. I have stripped it down to a testcase (which does not make any sense but shows the problem). In Hibernate 5 the following query to a generic field `name` runs fine whereas Hibernate 6 throws an Exception.

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = eMgr.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> cr = cb.createQuery(String.class);
Root<Person> person = cr.from(Person.class);
cr.select(person.<String> get("name"));
TypedQuery<String> query = eMgr.createQuery(cr);
```

Exception:

```
Converting `org.hibernate.query.QueryTypeMismatchException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : Specified result type [java.lang.String] did not match Query selection type [java.lang.Object] - multiple selections: use Tuple or array
```

Here are my sample class definitions:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class GenericPerson<T>
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    private long id;
    private T name;

    public GenericPerson()  {   }
    public GenericPerson(T name)    { this.name = name;}

    public T getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(T name) {   this.name = name;   }

    public long getId() { return this.id;}
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
}

@Entity
public class Person extends GenericPerson<String>
{
    public Person() { }
    public Person(String name) {    super(name);    }
}
```

Hibernate 5 seems to handle generics differently to Hibernate 6 but I could not find any hint in the migration document. Why fails the test case with Hibernate 6?

Comment: I'm seeing this generics problem as well.  It's definitely a blocker for my migration up to Hibernate 6/Spring Boot 3.

Comment: Did you solved the problem? I have the same problem and, in my case, I think the problem is this line `builder.in(laboratori.get("id")).value(subqueryLaboratori)` where the value is a `Subquery` object instead of a String, Integer, Long... 
With Spring 2.7.2 it worked but after the migration to 3.0.6 it breaks.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem in the migration guides https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html and https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/migration-guide/migration-guide.html. Read carefully because they are long, but provide all the necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the cast method for the generic field:

```java
cr.select(person.get("name").as(String.class));
```

Comment: This don't work for me. We have Generics with Inheritence like
----
Foo extends BaseEntity<FooId>
---
BaseEntity<S extends UUID>
private S id;
--- 
FooID extends UUID