# Upgrading from Spring Boot 2.6.7 to 3.0.5 Spring Data JPA Dynamic Projection errors at Runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In trying to upgrade from Spring Boot 2.6.7 to 3.0.5, my Dynamic Projection code that has been working for quite some time now fails with errors at runtime.  It doesn't matter if it's just a JPA Query Method or an @Query annotated method.  The reference docs still show examples of doing this for JPA, though I do see the [Note](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos) in this section that seems to indicate Dynamic Projections no longer work with @Query.  Is that correct?  Is this called out and explained anywhere other than in this Note?

```
// WAS - this is what has worked, and I would like to keep
// individualDtoResponse = individualRepository.findById(existingIndividual.getId(), IndividualDTO.class);

// NOW - a workaround hack thats ugly!
Individual temp = individualRepository.findById(existingIndividual.getId(), Individual.class);
individualDtoResponse = new IndividualDTO(temp);
```

```
// Repo / Query Method
@Repository
public interface IndividualRepository extends JpaRepositoryRep<Individual, Integer>
{
    <T> T findById(Integer id, Class<T> projection);
```

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Specified result type [...IndividualDTO] did not match Query selection type [...Individual] - multiple selections: use Tuple or array
```

All I've found using my Google fu is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75169414/hibernate-6-regression-with-generics) that sounds related, but I'm using Spring Data JPA not CriteraBuilder.

Can you help me identify the problem and how do I fix it?  Is there a doc or guide I'm just not finding?

Comment: Did you get your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [jpa reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos), `record` should be used for Class-based Projections (DTOs) (Check their example with NamesOnly - note that **`record` is a valid keyword since java 14**). As a result, you can redefine your DTO as below:

```
public record IndividualDTO (
    // variable 1
    // variable 2
) {}
```

Then, the below query will work:

```
individualDtoResponse = 
    individualRepository.findById(existingIndividual.getId(), IndividualDTO.class);
```

Comment: not must, should, It is said htat record are ideal but the requirement is having a cosntructor with the needed attributes "Alternatively, you can use any class that defines the properties you want to project."

Comment: @pdem - I think the problem has something to do with the hibernate behind also. In my case, I use hibernate 6.3.1, (6.2.9 before) and in both cases, I can only use record. I mean, Spring supports both ways, but maybe it's not the case for Hibernate here. I can only see their not-much-related doc here - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause